# MySQL - Multiple Queries or Single Query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-performance

So I have a table that contains votes. The relevant columns for this issue being `user` and `timestamp`.

I need to grab the user's **total** vote count, and also their votes **this month**.

I know the queries - I'm not asking for those. I use these at the same time:

Votes this month / Total votes:

```
SELECT COUNT( 0 ) FROM votes WHERE ( timestamp BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) ,'%Y-%m-01' ) AND NOW( ) ) AND user = ?;

SELECT COUNT( 0 ) FROM votes WHERE user = ?;
```

At the moment, my database isn't large enough (or even queried enough) to where performance is an issue. However, that's expected to change shortly. Should I keep the queries separate, or should I:

```
SELECT COUNT( 0 ) AS totalVotes,
       SUM( IF( timestamp BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) ,'%Y-%m-01' )
                              AND NOW( ), 1, 0 ) ) AS votesThisMonth
    FROM votes WHERE user = ?;
```

What is the best practice? Are there any tips for querying multiple bits of information from the same table to prevent having to search it twice? Is my combined query even what I **should** be using?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you use `count(0)` instead of `count(*)` (the standard) or `count(1)` (which to me makes semantic sense)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, I would recommend:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalVotes,
       SUM(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM timestamp) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM NOW())) AS votesThisMonth
FROM votes
WHERE user = ?;
```

An alternative to the above is:

```
 SUM(timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - (DAY(CURRENT_DATE) - 1) DAY)
```

I strongly discourage you from using strings for dates, unless you really have to.  There are multiple ways to get values from the current date that do NOT involves implicitly or explicitly converting a date/time value to a string.

Also, the `IF()` is redundant.  MySQL allows you to just add up boolean values.  Neither is standard SQL, so you might as well use the more concise version.

The `COUNT(0)` is jarring to me.  Although it works, `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)` seem simpler.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon - your tips were very helpful. Your votesThisMonth is much easier to read and understand. Also, I didn't know about MySQL adding booleans.

Comment: @Stev . . . You are free to accept whatever answer you think is best.  Based on your comments, I'm surprised you didn't accept this one.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the second solution, that uses a unique query with a conditional sum.

Rationale: to produce the second resultset, you need to scan a *subset* of the first resultset. So the additional processing needed is quite tiny anyway. On the other hand, running two separate queries involves one more roundtrip to the server, one more query parse for the query planner, and an additional scan on the table.

For performance, you want an index on `(user, timestamp)`.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different, not necessarily faster than other suggestions:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total,
       SUM(LEFT(timestamp, 7) = LEFT(NOW(), 7)) AS this_month
    FROM tbl
    WHERE user_id = ?
```

And have

```
INDEX(user_id, timestamp) -- in this order.  ("Covering")
```

Back to the question of 1 vs 2 queries:

- My combined query makes one scan over all rows for the user.
- The 'total' query also needs one scan over all rows for the user.
- The 'this month' query, if using `BETWEEN` or `>=` makes a scan over just the rows for the user this month.  (Mine fails to do that, but it does not matter.)